# Why is ARP needed in a host - router system if the router already has list of addresses it assigned using dhcp?

Tags: computer-networks

The hosts are assigned IP address by the router using dhcp. So, the router has a list (mac addresses) of all the hosts that are directly connected to it as well their ip addresses.
Now if a packet comes from outside, the router must be able to find the destination mac address from its logs. Then what is the need to use ARP in such a case (hosts connected to router)?

The only time I see an use of ARP is when router has to find new routers. Using ARP allows it to find new routers as well as to force a more rigid use of longest matching address method if needed. However what is the use of ARP during "router to host" packet transfer?

Comment: there are some sophisticated algorithms running in routers to handle "adjacent router" tables, but this is maybe more of a networking question, see eg [understanding arp routers](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5418/understanding-arp-and-routers) / [networkengineering.se]

Answer (score 3):

The fact that the router has the list does not help when computer A wants to talk to computer B, because neither of the two has the list.